# Cannot convert msal loginPopup to loginRedirect ReactJS Azure Adb2c

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

## **This code works fine with msal.loginPopup()**

**Scenario**
I am using Azure Adb2c SSO to sign in to my react application. I have implemented everything successfully I am using **msalInstance.loginpopup()** to display the Microsoft ADB2C popup for the login. **Everything is working fine**. Now I want to** change the popup to redirect** but when I change it, It does redirect me to Microsoft ADB2C login page as expected but after successful sign in, redirects me back to the main login page of my application (where the user was initially when they pressed the login button).

## Remember this code works fine with msal.loginPopup()

**Code**
This is my function that is called when the login button on my react application login page is clicked.
**When I change it to msalInstane.loginRedirect it does not call the ***.then* block and redirects back to my react application login page.

**With successful login it redirects to agent dashboard as sow in the loginAgent function**

## When button is clicked

```
 const tryAgentLogin = () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
    message.info("Please enter your credentials in the login popup.");
    msalInstance 
      .loginPopup({                                        ** *//I change to loginRedirect here***
        redirectUri: ADB2C_AGENT_REDIRECT_URI,
        popupWindowAttributes: {
          popupSize: {
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth,
          },
          popupPosition: {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
          },
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("TOKEN RETURNED BY ADB2C", res);
        LoginAgent(
          res.idToken,
          setAuth,
          navigate,
          routes,
          setPageLoading,
          msalInstance
        );
      });
  };
```

## Logout Function

```
export const LoginAgent = (
  accessToken,
  setAuth,
  navigate,
  routes,
  setPageLoading,
  msalInstance
) => {
  axios
    .get(`${BASE_URL}${GET_AGENT_CLAIM_DATA}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res?.data?.success) {
        setPageLoading(false);
        message.success("Login successful");
        setAuth(res?.data);
        initAxiosGlobalConfigs(res?.data);

        navigate(`${routes.AGENT_DASHBOARD}?page=1&pageSize=10`);
      } else {
        showUnauthorizedMessage(msalInstance, message, setPageLoading);
      }
    });
};
```

## This code works fine as is but with loginRedirect() mentioned in the code it does not work.